# Does a leger board for a vaulted ceiling need to be beveled?

Tags: framing, ledger, gable

I'm designing a bathroom addition to my house. Due to existing roof lines, the ceiling will be vaulted to give more interior space on one side while maintaining minimum headroom on the other and not making the roof *too* flat. There will be a leger board attached to the existing house framing from which the ceiling joists will be hung via appropriate joist hangers.

This image shows the gable end wall of the addition (the existing house is to the right in the image, and not included in the drawing). The ledger is the top board (end-on view), with the doubled top plate of the gable-end wall below, and the ceiling joist (to the left) ready to be slid into position and have the appropriate angle cut made.

[image]

Can the bottom of this leger board be left with the factory square edge (the green line), or does it need to be beveled (the red line)?

It will, of course, be much easier to install the ledger if the builder doesn't have to rip the edge, but having it ripped will make it easier for me to install the drywall ceiling later.

Comment: I always figure that two pieces meeting together should match the full amount, instead of meeting at a point.  Especially if it is a supporting structure.  Also looks like you care about your work.

Comment: I figured that as well, @crip659. And I'm glad that my concern shows through. :) As I was writing up the question, I realized that _not_ beveling the edge would make hanging drywall more difficult, but figured I'd go ahead and ask anyway. Now I'm wondering about beveling the rim joist at the low end. I guess I draw it right and let the contractor worry about cutting & fitting it. :D

Comment: Oh come on...You know what you want to do. Have at it man.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, Skillion roof lean-to, not vaulted ceiling, and you want the rafters to finish flush with the bottom of the ledger.

so long as everything is sufficiently over sized I don't see a problem with bevelling the underside of the ledger. In skilled hands a hand-held circular saw is probably up-to the task as you don't need a furniture-grade bevel here.

Be sure to give the builder clear instructions showing how to install the rafters and joist hangers so that everything lines up.

on the other hand, the drywall glue can probably deal with the wedge-shaped void that will be left if you don't bevel.

Comment: Can you expand on the drywall glue idea? In my mind, the drywall wouldn't even make it to this ledger board, so I'm not sure where the glue would go. (I'll probably have it beveled anyway, I'm just curious what your thought it here.)

Comment: basically I just mean line the bottom of the rafters up with the back of the ledger,  this will leave a triangular 2" wide by 1/4" deep gap below the ledger  if you're glueing and screwing the drywall the glue will fill that gap well enough